# Unable to print file name from a list of file using dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of files in a directory. I want to iterate through the filenames and call a function if a particular file extension is found

```
def files():
    files = os.listdir()
#     files = ['abc.Jpg','ferf.jpg','vber.pdf','uvier.xlsx']

    for file in files:
        if file.lower().endswith('.jpg'):
            name= Dict['jpg']
            name(file)
        elif file.lower().endswith('.pdf'):
            e= Dict['pdf']
            e(file)
        elif file.lower().endswith('.xlsx'):
            f= Dict['xlsx']
            f(file)
        else:
            print('no file found')
            return 

def jpg(d):
    print('image file found {}'.format(file))

def pdf(e):
    print('pdf file found {}'.format(file))

def xlsx(f):
    print('excel file found {}'.format(file))


Dict={"jpg":jpg, "pdf":pdf,"xlsx":xlsx }
files()
```

This is my code. I am facing two problems here.

1. If I am selecting the files from directory it is not iterating and giving output **'no file found'**
2. If I am feeding a list manually instead of printing separate file names it is only printing the first file name repeatedly

Why is wrong in this code? Thanks in advance

Comment: `return` immediately breaks out of the function. The first file has the `.Jpeg` extension (capital J), which you haven't accounted for, so your `else` condition in the loop is `True` and you break out of `files`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are taking the wrong argument from the function parameter and should remove the `return` from `else` statement:
Correct code will be:

```py
import os

def files():
    files = os.listdir()

    file_found_flag = False
    for file in files:
        if file.lower().endswith('.jpg'):
            name= Dict['jpg']
            name(file)
            file_found_flag = True
        elif file.lower().endswith('.pdf'):
            e= Dict['pdf']
            e(file)
            file_found_flag = True

        elif file.lower().endswith('.xlsx'):
            f= Dict['xlsx']
            f(file)
            file_found_flag = True

    if not file_found_flag:
        print('no file found')


def jpg(file):
    print('image file found {}'.format(file))

def pdf(file):
    print('pdf file found {}'.format(file))

def xlsx(file):
    print('excel file found {}'.format(file))


Dict={"jpg":jpg, "pdf":pdf,"xlsx":xlsx }
files()
```

Comment: This is in my opinion the correct answer. It addresses the main issue of seeing the `no file found` error. Additionally, I would suggest adding an `else` clause to the extension branching. With a `logging.debug()` or something similar. It would make it easier to spot unexpected errors which are silent right now.

Comment: thank you so much. It worked. Now I understand what went wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can cleanly do it like this

```
EXT_IMAGES = ['.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.bmp', '.svg']
EXT_VIDEOS = ['.mp4', '.mkv', '.webm', '.mpeg', '.flv', '.m4a', '.f4v', '.f4a', '.m4b', '.m4r', '.f4b', '.mov', '.avi', '.wmv']
EXT_AUDIOS = ['.mp3', '.wav', '.raw', '.wma']
EXT_EXCEL = ['.xlsx']

def check_files():
    files = os.listdir()
    for file in files:
        filename, extension = os.path.splitext(file)
        if extension in EXT_IMAGES:
            print('image file found {}'.format(file))
        elif extension in EXT_VIDEOS:
            print('video file found {}'.format(file))
        elif extension in EXT_AUDIOS:
            print('audio file found {}'.format(file))
        elif extension in EXT_EXCEL:
            print('excel file found {}'.format(file))
        else:
            print('unknown file found: %s' % file)

check_files()
```

Comment: I _suspect_ that the dictionary of functions has more importance than simply `print`, and this functionality is lost with your approach

Comment: from my point of view is he used `Dict` with samples of data for testing, it looks redudant anyway

Comment: He can still call his functions from if block anyway. It's not like anything is broken!

Comment: I didn't say it was broken. It looks like they were going for a dispatch method

Answer (score 0):

A few of things I noticed that might be wrong in your code:

1. file is a builtin in Python. You might want to change your variable name to something other than file.

   ```
   for f in files:
       if f.lower().endswith('.jpg'):
           name= Dict['jpg']
           name(f)
       elif f.lower().endswith('.pdf'):
           e= Dict['pdf']
           e(f)
       elif f.lower().endswith('.xlsx'):
           func= Dict['xlsx']
           func(f)
       else:
           print('no file found')
           return
   ```
2. You are using the incorrect argument in your jpeg, xlsx, and pdf methods.

   def jpg(d):
       print('image file found {}'.format(d))

The output produced in my case:

```
image file found abc.Jpg
image file found ferf.jpg
pdf file found vber.pdf
excel file found uvier.xlsx
```

Comment: `file` is not a builtin in Python 3 and you really shouldn't be using Python 2, it's about to lose future support.